# search inside one string and eliminate the found positions in an accompanying list

Tags: python, string, search

I have a string with text and an accompanying list with information about each character in the first list. For example:

```
text="this, and this are test elems"
textInfo=[1, 4, 6, 7, ,8, 3, 6, 2, 4, ... 7, 0]
```

where each position in the list refers to a character is the text, i.e. len(text) == len(textInfo) where textInfo[i] has info on the ith character in text.

I want to eliminate the instances of "this" in the text, and eliminate as well the positions in the list that refer to those characters (i.e. 4 positions, corresponding to the information about "t", "h", "i" and "s").

My brute force approach would be something like:

```
tmpText = text
tmpTextInfo = textInfo
m = re.search("this", tmpText)
while m:
  tmpText = tmpText[0:m.start()] + tmpText[m.end():]
  tmpTextInfo =  tmpTextInfo[0:m.start()] + tmpTextInfo[m.end():]
  m = re.search("this", tmpText)
text = tmpText
textInfo = tmpTextInfo
```

This works and obtains what I expect. For example:
If the input is

```
text = "this test this is"
textInfo = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
```

Then the resulting text and textInfo strings will be

```
text=" test  is"
textInfo=[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15, 16]
```

But it looks to me to be non-pythonic at all, and I am sure there are more compact and efficient ways to do it, is it?

Comment: Add your output too .... It will help us

Comment: Your result string will be `, and  are test elems`?

Comment: What you mean by `corresponds` ???? can you describe the logic behind this word??

Comment: how does the list "textinfo" correlates to the string "test"?

Comment: I have explained a bit better the problem and the output I would obtain with an example. I think this is a legitimate question and I am sure there are much better and python ways to do it.

Comment: @Kasra I changed corresponds to refers, I hope this is clearer for you. I also inserted an example of what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't think I'd do it any differently if you actually need a regular expression. You could at most just store the list of strings to keep and join them at the end but it wouldn't improve readability.

If the issue is about removing tokens separated by space or punctuation, you could use a generator to yield a pair of token with corresponding  `textInfo`. Then you could filter based on token (or attached info if you want) and reassemble both lists. But I'm not sure it'd bring anything, really.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I marked it as correct because I ended up using the code I proposed in my post (which is what you indicate you would do). Still, I am puzzled that this is the best way to do it (it looks very ugly) and that people consider the question as not interesting...